# How to identify overridden methods from libraries with ASM library?

Tags: java, android, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm using ASM to collect some information about the classes in an Android project (using a gradle plugin combined with the Google Transform API). I want to find if a method is overriding a method from his superclass/interfaces. If the superclass or the interface is part of the project or the local dependencies (jars) i can compare the descriptor of the current method against all the methods defined in the superclass/interface. This is done by traversing the entire hierarchy (bottom-up). If i find a match between the descriptors i've found an overridden method.

My problem appears when i reach a superclass/interface defined in a standard library (like `java.lang` or `android.app`, etc..) because i don't known how to visit this kind of classes. If the library class is in the current classpath i can access directly from the `ClassReader`.

For example:

```
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader("java.lang.Object");
```

But if the class is not in the current classpath i get (of course) `java.io.IOException: Class not found`. For example when i try:

```
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader("android.app.Activity");
```

From what i know, comparing the descriptors of two methods, is the only way to determine if one is overriding of the other, so i must visit the superclass/interface somehow.

So my question is:
**How can i visit a superclass/interface that is defined in a standard library**?
(note: not the dependencies inside the android project, that, i'm already able to evaluate), **or if there is another way to determine the override property**.

Comment: If you have the standard lib as jar, then you can create a class reader with an InputStream.

Comment: The problem is exactly that. I do not have the standard lib as a jar during the build in the android project, i can access the project source, the dependencies, the subprojects, everything the Transform API allow to see. But i can't access the stdlib

Comment: The classes must be in a format, the compiler can read, i.e. in a directory or jar file, as otherwise, it would be impossible to compile the project.